# Drag-Drop: cdkDragHandle and cdkDrag are not working

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I am setting up a new page which is like the below image

[image]

In this operation group should not be dragged into other three groups (all are given by div name- operationArea)

## Problem

Here the drag operation is working but can be dragged to other components. The problem is reproduced in Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyfknd
In this example the components are immovable.

## Steps so far I done

1. Developed a shared component(for single card view) which is

```
<div class="operationArea orders-drop-down">
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="drag_dropCard" 
*ngFor="let card of cardModel" cdkDragBoundary=".operationArea" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" cdkDrag>
      <mat-icon class="menu-icon" color="primary">{{card.icon}}</mat-icon>
      <span class="menu-title"> {{card.name}}</span>
      <mat-icon color="primary" (click)="editOperation(item)" class="c-pointer">edit</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon color="primary" (click)="deleteOperation(item)" class="c-pointer">delete</mat-icon>    
</div>
</div>
```

2. Developed another component to implement in large scale:(models are provided for multiplication)

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly start" style="height:90%;padding-top:.5em ">    
    <div>
        <drag-card-component [cardModel]='operationModel'>    
        </drag-card-component>
    </div>
    <div>
        <drag-card-component [cardModel]='actionModel'>    
        </drag-card-component>
    </div>
    <div>
        <drag-card-component [cardModel]='componentModel'>    
        </drag-card-component>      
    </div>
    <div>
        <drag-card-component [cardModel]='traceModel'>    
        </drag-card-component>        
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Binding:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.session.pageType = true; // for showing another icons in Moreoptions
    // initializing LUT
    this.orderTemplateFormGroup =  this.formBuilder.group({
        orderTemplate            :   ['', [Validators.required]],
     });

    this.operationModel =[
        {id: 1, name: 'Operation1', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 2, name: 'Operation2', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 3, name: 'Operation3', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 4, name: 'Operation4', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
    ];
    this.actionModel =[
        {id: 1, name: 'Action1', icon: 'build', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 2, name: 'Action2', icon: 'build', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 3, name: 'Action3', icon: 'build', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 4, name: 'Action4', icon: 'build', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
    ];
    this.componentModel =[
        {id: 1, name: 'component1', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 2, name: 'component2', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 3, name: 'component3', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 4, name: 'component4', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
    ];
    this.traceModel =[
        {id: 1, name: 'trace1', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 2, name: 'trace2', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 3, name: 'trace3', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
        {id: 4, name: 'trace4', icon: 'settings', hasSub : false, parentId:0},
    ];
}
```

The folder arrangement like this

```
+app
  -page
    --newcomponents.ts
  -sharedmodule
    --hello
      ---card.ts
      ---hellocomponent.ts
    --sharedmodule.ts
  -app.module.ts
  -app.component.ts(functionality transfered to newcomponents.ts)
```

Kindly explain, what did I miss?

Comment: Did you try adding the `cdkDropList` directive?

Comment: In your example, you are not actually importing `DragDropModule`, you are only exporting it currently. Without importing/registering `DragDropModule` in the NgModule `imports`,  `cdkDrag` or similar directives will simply not work. Here is an updated example with at least the module imported and dragging/dropping working at a basic level. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drax4a

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky, that was spot on. But I have doubt regarding the folder arrangement., so i re-edited the question.

Comment: @Will Alexander not yet, will require during the data binding

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky would u help me with above folder architecture..

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your structure, it should be fine. I usually use the application structure suggested by the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules), but that's just personal preference. In your situation, "page" would be a "feature module".

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, i am not getting the those operation after the above  architecture

Comment: In the `NewComponent` of your StackBlitz example, you are attempting to reference in `styleUrls` the stylesheet `'./app.component.css'`, this is preventing the app from loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast I got the answer based upon insights provided by @Will Alexander, after adding the 
**cdkDropList** ,
now the code is:

```
<mat-accordion  cdkDropList="cardModel" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let card of cardModel"  cdkDrag  (click)="displayOperation(card)" >  
                 <mat-expansion-panel-header>  
                <mat-icon class="menu-icon" color="primary" style="width:5%">{{card.icon}}</mat-icon>
                <span class="menu-title" color="primary" style="width:63%; font-size: 12px;padding:.2em"> {{card.name}}</span>
                <span style="padding-left:.5em" style="width:30%">
                <mat-icon color="accent" (click)="editOperation()" value="edit"  class="c-pointer">edit</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon color="warn"   (click)="deleteOperation()" value="delete" class="c-pointer">delete</mat-icon> 
                </span>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```